# Is ‘Er ist mit ihr verliebt’ correct?

Tags: preposition, phrase, verb-usage

Well I know the sentence would usually be:

> Er ist in sie verliebt.

But would it also be correct to say:

> Er ist mit ihr verliebt.

Comment: This is not standard German. It is either wrong, or poetry. Depends on your level of command of the language. As you are asking: in your case, it is wrong. But it would be a good piece of creative writing in appropriate context.

Comment: Well here goes one mistake. I had today exam and just couldnt able to think the right way of writing. Damn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sentence is — as is quite often the case for almost correct sentences — not really wrong but it does not mean what you think it means.

The verb and it's extension are: ***in** jemanden verliebt sein.* In contemporary German, this is the only option you have. (Maybe different forms were possible in the past but died out.) Thus, there is no way how *mit* in your example could introduce the prepositional object of the verb *verliebt sein* i.e. the target of the desire.

However, *mit* can also act as a simple proposition introducing an adverbial (i.e. not object-type) extension. In this case, *mit* generally means *(together) with.* Thus, you can use the sentence but it means ‘I am also in love (with the same person)’.

> Der Max ist total nett und so gutaussehend. Ich glaube, ich habe mich in ihn verliebt.
>
> Wie Recht du hast! Ich bin mit dir verliebt!

It only works if you either deliberately leave the context and target unclear or if you can infer them from context.

Comment: Damn. Fear got the best of me. I had an exam and I just couldnt able to think the right form. I knew something was off but still I couldnt able to find it.

Comment: @user204946  - Probably you will survive anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The verb commands the prepositions and their meaning. As most verbs, **verlieben** can take multiple objects.

The accusative object is mandatory, usually it's a reflexive pronoun. It's the person in love.

> Er verliebte sich.

It may take a prepositional object with *in*, which is the person or thing loved (in+accusative), or the way of falling in love (in+dative), or the place where it happened (in+dative):

> Er verliebte sich in den Wagen. (in+accusative)
>
> Er verliebte sich in Höchstgeschwindigkeit. *(ambiguous)*
>
> Er verliebte sich im Urlaub. (in+dative)

A prepositional object with *mit* or *ohne* also describes the way of falling in love.

> Er verliebte sich mit Höchstgeschwindigkeit.
>
> Er verliebte sich ohne zu zögern.

And of course, there could be obstacles, intensifiers,

> Er verliebte sich gegen/wider die Vernunft.
>
> Er verliebte sich über die Maße.

In combination:

> Er verliebte sich im Urlaub in Höchstgeschwindigkeit in den Wagen.

Comment: Shouldn't it usually be "über die Maßen", with "n"?

Comment: Ich kenn beides.

Comment: Es muss _Maße_ heißen, schließlich ist _das Maß_ etwas anderes als _die Maße_ (https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Masze). Das falsche zu kennen, ist ja kein Argument für dessen Richtigkeit. Es bleibt trotzdem falsch.

Comment: Na ja, dass *über die Maßen* grammatiklogisch unlogisch ist, sehe ich schon ein. Es klang mir nur so normal. Könnte es sein, dass es eine Fehlbildung ist nach dem Modell "wenn es *dermaßen* heißt, muss es auch *überdiemaßen* heißen"? - Die Frage nach Genese und Verbreitung des *über die Maßen* wäre freilich eine eigenes Thema hier. Der dicke Duden neuerer Ausgabe kennt *über die Maßen* übrigens nicht. Aber auch nicht *über die Maße*, oder jedenfalls findichsnich. Komisch. Solche Wendungen sind doch üblicherweise verzeichnet?

Answer (score 0):

It is rather

> Er ist in sie verliebt

or

> Sie sind verliebt

if you want to express mutual being-in-love.